# Algebra automorphisms and basis change

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a unital finite-dimensional assocoative non-commutative algebra over the field $\mathbb{C}$ and $b=\{e_1, e_2, \dots ,e_n\}$ it linear basis. Let $f_1 = e_1 + e_2$ and we complete $f_1$ to be a linear basis of $A$.

My question is: Does there exist an algebra automorphism on $A$ that sends $f_1$ to $e_1$?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried checking the case $e_1=1$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes a typo. Thanks

Comment: @Ruy Thank you, but I do not want to check special case/element. I want to know if there exist some propositions that trait something like that. I used *diagram chasing*, and this works for modules, but I do not know if this will work on algebras.

Comment: @Math-Rank-0 In what sense does this work for modules?

Answer (score 1):

This is not always possible and here is a counter-exmaple.  Take $A=M_2(\mathbb{C})$ with basis $\{e_{11},e_{22},e_{12},e_{21}\}$.  Then the sum of the first two basis elements is $$f_1=e_{11}+e_{22}=I,$$ namely the identity matrix.  Any automorphism of $A$ must send the identity matrix to itself so it cannot send $f_1$ to $e_{11}$.

Comment: Very nice. When can this be possible? do you have any references to recommend for this question? Thanks.

Comment: @Math-Rank-0 Here is an obvious necessary condition: the set of automorphisms of $A$ must act transitively on the non-zero elements of $A$, at least up to scalar multiples. This is clear because if $a$ and $b$ are two elements that are not scalar multiples, I can produce a basis starting $\{a,b-a\}$, and then your map sends $a$ to $b$. Needless to say, most algebras do not have this property.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thanks, what about adding the assumption: $a$ and $b$ are nilpotent and for every $x\in A$ we have $ax=xa=bx=xb = 0$. Let $f$ be a linear map that sends $a$ to $b$, $b-a$ to $a$ and other basis elements to themself. In this case, $f$ maybe an algbera authomorphism?

Comment: @Math-Rank-0 Your algebra is unital, so how can a and b annihilate the algebra? Even if A were not unital, I don't see why two elements that annihilate the algebra need to be in the same orbit under the action of the automorphism group. For example, the rest of the algebra could force Aut(A) to be quite small.